# How "Algebrization" is "A New Barrier in Complexity Theory"?

Tags: complexity-classes, time-complexity

Being an enthusiast in computational complexity theory, I recently came across with this wonderful work [Algebrization: A New Barrier in Complexity Theory](https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/alg.pdf).

My question is about Theorem 5.3 in it (pp. 23-24).

It states that "there exists an oracle $A$ and an algebrization $\tilde{A}$ of $A$ such that $\mathbf{NP}^A\not\subset\mathbf{P}^\tilde{A}$. Furthermore, the language $L$ that achieves this separation simply corresponds to deciding, on input length $n$, whether there exists a $w\in\{0,1\}^n$ with $A_n(w)=1$."

The basic idea of its proof is to consider the oracle $A$ as a Boolean function $A_n:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}$, while $\tilde{A}$ is a multi-quadratic extension $\tilde{A}_{n,\mathbb{F}}:\mathbb{F}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ of $A$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}$. Now, they define the language, $$L=\{1^n \mid \exists w\in\{0,1\}^n \land A_n(w)=1\}.$$ For all $A$, $L\in\mathbf{NP}^A$. Now, they construct $\tilde{A}$ in such a way so that $L\notin \mathbf{P}^\tilde{A}$.

Therefore, it says that **there exists** an algebrization (i.e., $\tilde{A}$) which shows the separation $\mathbf{NP}^A\not\subset\mathbf{P}^\tilde{A}$. So, they infer that we need non-algebrization in order to prove $\mathbf{NP}\subset\mathbf{P}$. But does this theorem prove that **for all** algebrization $\tilde{A}$ (w.r.t. $A$) we have, $\mathbf{NP}^A\not\subset\mathbf{P}^\tilde{A}$? More specifically, how to refute the existence of at least one algebrization $\tilde{A}$ that may prove $\mathbf{NP}^A\subset\mathbf{P}^\tilde{A}$?

Comment: Exactly. Thank you for this explanation. But it is not me rather the authors who inferred that "The second set of results shows that, for many basic complexity questions, any solution will **require** non-algebrizing technique" (pp. 3). Clearly this may not be the case.

Comment: You seem to be missing something quite basic about the logic of the argument. The conclusion of the authors is perfectly correct. Any algebrizing technique that resolves the NP vs. P question will in fact show that $\mathrm{NP}^{\tilde A}\nsubseteq\mathrm P^{\tilde A}$ for all $A$, or that $\mathrm{NP}^A\subseteq\mathrm P^{\tilde A}$ for all $A$. Since there are counterexamples showing that both these statements are false, no algebrizing technique can resolve the NP vs. P question.

Comment: This is exactly what my question was. Can you kindly specify which theorem says that "**any** algebrizing technique shows that $\mathbf{NP}^A\not\subset\mathbf{P}^\tilde{A}$? Theorem 5.3 does not do this. The extension $\tilde{A}$ of $A$ in Theorem 5.3 talks about **a particular** algebrization. In order to prove the separation for **any** algebrization, it must consider all efficiently computable algebrization. However, Theorem 5.1 correctly says that $\mathbf{NP}^\tilde{B}\subset\mathbf{P}^B$ for **any** algebrization. Its proof is independent of any particular algebrization of $B$.

Comment: Further, Theorem 5.1 and 5.3 do not contradict each other unless their proofs use the same algebrization, say $\tilde{A}$. Even if they, it would mean that $\mathbf{P}$ vs. $\mathbf{NP}$ is unsolvable using that particular $\tilde{A}$. How to refute the existence of another algebrization, say $\tilde{B}$, that contradicts Theorem 5.3 but admits to Theorem 5.1?

Comment: Theorems 5.1 and 5.3 are both *theorems*, hence it would be very, very, very bad if they contradicted each other. Again, you seem to misunderstand the definition of the concepts. If $\let\R\mathrm\def\tA{\tilde A}\R{NP\subseteq P}$ can be proved by a technique that algebrizes, then *by definition* this means that $\R{NP}^A\subseteq\R P^\tA$ for *all* $A$ and *all* low-degree extensions $\tA$. But this is false, since there *exist* $A$ and $\tA$ such that $\R{NP}^A\nsubseteq\R P^\tA$ by Thm. 5.3. Thus, the premise fails: $\R{NP\subseteq P}$ *cannot* be proved by a technique that algebrizes. ...

Comment: ... Likewise: if $\let\R\mathrm\def\tA{\tilde A}\R{NP\nsubseteq P}$ can be proved by a technique that algebrizes, then *by definition* this means that $\R{NP}^\tA\nsubseteq\R P^A$ for *all* $A$ and *all* $\tA$. But this is false, since there *exist* $A$ and $\tA$ such that $\R{NP}^\tA\subseteq\R P^A$ by Thm. 5.1. Thus, the premise fails: $\R{NP\nsubseteq P}$ *cannot* be proved by a technique that algebrizes. Putting the two together: no technique that algebrizes can resolve the NP vs. P question either way. This is the "barrier".